# Solution of Quadratic Equation: Must be between 0, 1

Tags: calculus

It is given that

$$p = \frac{2\chi_0 + \chi_1 - \lambda c}{\chi_0 + \chi_1}$$

I want to find out something meaningful about the parameters inside $p$, such as necessary conditions such that the following holds:

$$ \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - 1} - \frac{p}{2} \in [0, 1] $$

What would be a good approach? I could square the left-hand-side of the condition, as that would not touch the right-hand-side. It seems to yield quite a mess though. Would that be a good approach or is there something better to be done with this?

Comment: What's the relation of your question's title with the question's body??

Comment: @Timbuc For the quadratic equation $0 = x^2 + px + 1$, the solution is given by $x = -p/2 +- \sqrt{p^2/4 - 1}$. The condition requires one of these solutions to be between zero and unity.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $\sqrt{\dfrac{p^2}{4} - 1} - \dfrac{p}{2} \in [0, 1]$ means the greatest (real) root of $f(x)=x^2+px+1$ is between $0$ and $1$.

The first condition is having real roots  $x_0, x_1$, which happens if $\lvert p\rvert \ge 2$. Since $f(0)=1$, $0$ is *not* between $x_0$ and $x_1$, so $x_0,x_1$ have the same sign, in which case it is also the sign of $x_0+x_1=-p$. Thus $f(x)$ has two negative roots if $p>0$.

If $p<0$, there are $3$ possible configurations:
$$(\mathrm i)\enspace 0<x_0\le x_1<1, \quad (\mathrm{ii})\enspace 0 <x_0 \le 1 \le x_1, \quad (\mathrm{iii})\enspace 0 < 1 < x_0\le x_1. $$
Formally, cases (i) and (iii) correspond to the condition: $f(1)=p+2>0$, i. e. $\,p>-2$. However, if $-2 <p<0$, there is no real root. So we must be in case (ii).

Case (ii) corresponds to $p\le-2$; note that, if $\,p=-2$, $\,x_0=x_1=1$.

*Conclusion:* 
 $$\sqrt{\dfrac{p^2}{4} - 1} - \dfrac{p}{2} \in [0, 1] \iff p\le -2.$$

Comment: (+1) I was trying to salvage my answer, but I'm glad you've beat me to it.

Comment: @pjs36: When I began high school, we were taught to be very careful with (in)equations with irrationals, and if possible to avoid them…  We can get a lot of information just looking at the relations between coefficients and roots of quadratic equations, without ever having to compute the roots.