# Quadratic equation: Between 0 and 1

Tags: calculus

I was previously asking a similar question, but with the wrong sign. Since I found the answer there quite valuable on its own, I didn't want to derail the post by editing. Hence, here's a second try.

The solutions for $x$ in

$$ 0 = 1 + px + x^2,\\
p = \frac{2\chi_0 + \chi_1 - \lambda c}{\chi_0 + \chi_1}$$

are given by

$$ x = -p/2 \stackrel{+}{-} \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - 1}$$

I want to find out as much as possible on the parameter requirements within $p$ that give me

$$ x \in [0, 1]$$. [As I already learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245434/solution-of-quadratic-equation-must-be-between-0-1) (*or maybe I didn't? The answer was deleted*), one of the solutions will never be positive (I suspected this, but removed the wrong sign/solution).

Hence, we are left with

$$ p/2  + \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - 1} \in [0, 1]$$

How would I proceed in understanding some requirements on $p$ and the underlying parameters that give me this condition? I already tried

$$ p/2  + \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - 1} \leq 1 \\
\frac{p^2}{4} - 1 \leq (1 - p/2)^2 \\
p \leq 2 $$

Was this transformation correct? If I try the same for the other inequality ($x \geq 0$), I get a contradiction: $0 \geq 1$. I'm confused: Does that mean that *none* of the solutions to $0 = 1 + px + x^2$ is positive?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $|p|\ge 2$ or $\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-1}$ is not real. But if $p>2$, then $\frac{p}{2}>1$ and $\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-1}>0$, so the root is not in $[0,1]$. So the only positive value of $p$ for which the root lies in $[0,1]$ is $p=2$.

If $p\le-2$, then $\frac{p}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-1}<0$ and approaches zero asymptotically as $p\to -\infty$, so there are no negative values of $p$ for which the root lies in $[0,1]$.

So the only solution is $p=2$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?